# how to show only one id loop jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in jquery. So I feel greatful who help to solve my problem.
I am simply want to add class hidden in all of div blocks but to show only which should be come form click of button id.

My jquery code is:-

```
$('.editFunding'+(fundingCounter-1)).click(function () {
    var editID=$(this).attr('id');
     $("#funding"+editID).show();
     var i;
     for(i=0;i<editID && i> editID; i++)
     {
         $("#funding"+i). addClass("hidden");
      }
  });
```

I just want to add class hidden each of loop inside of the for loop at time.
But This code does not work.
So I feel Thankful for those who can be help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: `editFunding` is a class or id?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML, also I don't understand this part at all "I am simply want to add class hidden in all of div blocks but to show only which should be come form click of button id."

Comment: editFunding is  class

Comment: and class name should be changed one by number to click on button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop while you can use a selector to select all elements with id starts with funding `$('[id^="funding"]')` and show the element with id you need to show .. so you need to arrange your code like this

```
$('[id^="funding"]').addClass("hidden");     // add class for all
$("#funding"+editID).removeClass("hidden");  // remove class for wanted id
```

or you can use `hide()` and `show()`

```
$('[id^="funding"]').hide();
$("#funding"+editID).show();
```

While your all blocks ids starts with `funding` and your buttons class starts with `editFunding` So your code should looks like

```
$('[class^="editFunding"]').click(function () {
    var editID=$(this).attr('id');
    $('[id^="funding"]').addClass("hidden");     // add class for all
    $("#funding"+editID).removeClass("hidden");  // remove class for wanted id
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. @Mohamed-Yousef. But it's hide all the funding blocks

Comment: @PawanDongol I update my answer .. check it again it should work while your blocks ids starts with `funding` and buttons class starts with `editFunding`